# Stuck with DHCP option 43/60 with ISC

Tags: isc-dhcp, dhcp-option, debian-bookworm

if´ve already checked the existing threads for option 43, but I don´t get it for my case.
I want to implement a thin-client auto-registration in our productive thin-client subnet - and I´m not DHCPD Pro, just used simples setting yet.

The vendor said:"
Alternatively you can use DHCP option 43 (vendor-specific options) to send DHCP option 224 (name: igelrmserver) to the correct endpoints. An end device with IGEL OS 11.04.100 or higher sends the option 60 (vendor class identifier) with igel-dhcp-1 as value.
An IGEL-specific DHCP option that is sent in DHCP option 43 overrides a corresponding DHCP option that is sent in the global namespace. The DHCP options 1, 224, and 226 can be embedded in option 43.
You can prevent a DHCP option 224 that has been sent in the global namespace from being interpreted. To achieve this, you must add option 1 (called "exclusive", type Byte, value 1) to DHCP option 43.
"

[Here is my dhcpd.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gh9U.png)

I did many tryouts and leave the most in this screenshot.
I have no clue what I´m doing wrong, some hints or examples would be great.

Bests Marc

Answer (score 1):

I see that in your dhcpd.conf you wrote:

```
##Configure the "server-address" parameter for the Option Space. Use code 1 
option igelrmserver.server-address = array of ip-address;
```

but in a similar configuration I have:

```
option AP-AirEngine5761-21.server-address code 1 = array of ip-address;
```

From your comment I assume you're trying to push Option43 with SubOption1 encoded, but from what I read, you can't push the suboption without specifying the code adding the block "code 1".

An example from Extreme Networks official documentation:
https://documentation.extremenetworks.com/XIQC/10.07.01/DG/GUID-A9F28828-9A51-4923-AE62-A252E4745D73.shtml